# Kaltura bulk upload using csv file

Tags: csv, kaltura

How to add ssh public key and private key in a csv file for sftp protocol .
I want to bulk upload to kaltura using a csv file.
I have a video in my kaltura ce4.
I want to have pull mechanism to kaltura through sftp transfer protocol.
My file url is-->>sftp://ec2-user@ec2-54-245-118-246.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/home/ec2-user/video.mp4

Now i must give public and private key also in my csv file since its sftp.
I dont know how to give the keys there in csv file.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve import that requires key authentication, you will need to use drop folders instead of bulk upload.
[Kaltura Drop Folders, Knowledge Center](http://knowledge.kaltura.com/kaltura-drop-folders)